# Facebook & Twitter share button stopped working

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, button, share

Recently I had it working, but now it just stopped out of nowhere. The buttons do nothing when they are pressed. Thhe code doesn't even give breakpoint or errors. What is wrong?

[Download Project (3.2mb)](http://www.mediafire.com/?n5bj8npl8y369nr)

```
- (IBAction)ShareFB
{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [slComposeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-carrito.png"]];
        [slComposeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No FB Account" message:@"There are no FB account registered. Configure one" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)ShareTW
{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [slComposeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-carito.png"]];
        [slComposeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No TW Account" message:@"There are no TW accounts registered. Configure one." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want us to debug your code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, your first scene has its class set to `ViewController`, but in actually it should obviously be  one of the classes included in your project, e.g. `Tab1_ViewController`.

Comment: This worked. Thank You! Would you be willing to voice-chat with me to dix/make some other stuff?

Comment: @AlexPjz Feel free to post additional questions on S.O. and if you don't get sufficient answers (and/or I don't happen to see the question posted), add a comment here, and I'll make an effort to take a look at it.